# How to store ALAuthorizationStatus in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I want to store `ALAuthorizationStatus` in `NSDictionary` but I keep getting a warning from Xcode change `%ld` to `%d` and when I do that I get warning change `%d` to `%ld`. How to fix it.

```
 NSDictionary *dict = @{@"authStatusKey" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",[self authorizationStatus]];
```

Comment: Do you need it as a `NSString` or a `NSNumber` could be enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by using type casting:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"authStatusKey" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long int)[self authorizationStatus]];
```